# How to pass dart variable to index.html

Tags: flutter, environment-variables, flutter-web

I've been working on my flutter app with environnent builds, and i would like to modify my index.html file depending on the type of web build I am doing.

Is there a way to do so?
I have an env.dart which contains the variables I need but i don't know how to modify the index.html with my dart variable.

Thanks you.

Comment: This isn't really a great answer, but when I've needed to do this in the past, I've written a python build script that modifies the html file, and then runs my build commands.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution with shellscript

I currently use one but it is a shell script

#### Setup your environment-specific index.html

From your project folder create the environment where you will store your index.html files:

```
mkdir config
cd config
mkdir release
mkdir dev
mkdir uat
```

Then copy your different index.html (especially the one from web/) to config/release/ config/dev/ and config/uat/

```
cp ../web/index.html release/ && cp ../web/index.html dev/ && cp ../web/index.html uat/
```

**/!\ MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR CURRENT FILE LOCATED IN WEB/INDEX.HTML**
The script will copy index.html from your different environments directories directly to web/ and erase the current file in web/. I decline any liability should you permanently delete the file. You are warn.

---

#### Script file

Create the script file:

```
touch run.sh && chmod +x run.sh
```

copy this script inside:

```sh
cp config/$1/index.html web/index.html && flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety
```

---

#### How to use

And run it with either **`./run.sh release`, `./run.sh dev` or `./run.sh dev`**

#### Use --dart-define for your environment-specific variable

I also run this script along with setting environment variables with `--dart-define`

```
flutter run --dart-define=MY_ENV_VARIABLE=ITS_VALUE
```

*NB: I currently disable null-safety because of the libs of my project that are not yet null-safe.*